# Añadir imagen al final de pdf ya generado TCPDF FPDI

Tags: php, tcpdf

Tengo un pdf generado con TCPDF y quiero añadir varias imágenes al final del contenido. Las añado bien con FPDI pero no en la posición que necesito.
El contenido del pdf se genera dinámicamente y he intentado calcular la altura  pero no lo consigo:

```html
$pdf->MultiCell($w=0, $h=0, $contenido, $border=1, $align='L', $fill=false, $ln=1, $x='', $y='', $reseth=true, $stretch=0, $ishtml=false, $autopadding=true, $maxh=0);

// get the new Y
$end_y = $pdf->GetY();
$end_page = $pdf->getPage();
// calculate height
$height = 0;
if ($end_page == $start_page) {
    $height = $end_y - $start_y;
} else {
    for ($page=$start_page; $page <= $end_page; ++$page) {
  
        $pdf->setPage($page);
        if ($page == $start_page) {
            // first page
            $height = $pdf->getPageHeight() - $start_y - $pdf->getBreakMargin();
   
        } elseif ($page == $end_page) {
            // last page
            $height = $end_y - $pdf->getMargins()['top'];
   
        } else {
            $height = $pdf->getPageHeight() - $pdf->getMargins()['top'] - $pdf->getBreakMargin();
   
        }
    }
}
// restore previous object
$pdf = $pdf->rollbackTransaction();
```

También he intentado con $pdf->getNumLines($contenido, $width).

Pero ninguno de las dos formas es exacto y sobrescribo el contenido previo o se insertan en otra página.

Answer (score 0):

puedes intentar con esta linea de codigo que posiciona por coordenadas la imagen

```
$pdf->SetXY(110, 200);
$pdf->Image('images/image_demo.jpg', '', '', 40, 40, '', '', 'T', false, 300, '', false, false, 1, false, false, false);
```

[te dejo mas informacion](https://tcpdf.org/examples/example_009/)

Comment: Gracias por responder, con eso puedo insertar la imagen en una determinada posición, pero lo que necesito es saber en que posición acaba el contenido del pdf, el cuál cambia dinamicamente e insertar las imagenes justo debajo. Saludos